# how can I figure out when a branch in git was merged into the trunk

Tags: git, merge, branch, trunk

I'm trying to figure out the revision in the trunk when a branch was merged in, but I'm not sure how. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log --all --decorate --one-line --graph
```

will allow you to see the history without leaving the command line.

Comment: Actually that's perfect. Thank you.

Comment: It seems --one-line is not allowed anymore. (git 2.7.4)

Answer (score 1):

You can see network diagram on github.com for your repository. It will show flow diagram for all branches and whether or when they were merged with proper revision number.

Comment: u can check git log
try:
git log, it will show log of all commits and merges

Comment: Your initial suggestion will probably be more helpful than git log. Thanks. I'll be able to accept in 6 minutes.

Comment: Adam Dymitruk answered the question sufficiently, but your response was also very helpful. Thanks.